# Does a DVI-D source to VGA display converter exist at all?

Tags: dvi, vga, video-conversion, display-adapter

Does anyone know if a video converter (or adapter) exists that converts a DVI-D video source (for example from a laptop) to a VGA display (for example a projector)?

I understand that such a product would likely be price inhibited in most cases due to needing to process the digital signal and then output to an analog medium.  But i'm wondering if any exist at all.

FWIW my use case is a wall mounted projector in which we decided to run a VGA connection for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Please do not close as off-topic, [obscure hardware *is* welcome](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [one here](http://www.networktechinc.com/dvi-vga.html).

> The DVI to VGA Converter changes your computer's digital DVI signal to analog VGA video. The converter generates all the compatible digital to analog conversion signals to make the connection between the DVI-D input and the VGA output work.
>
> [image]

Comment: Strange male/female pin type choice, but it does come with the adapters for each side at least. Price is as expected too, wow, $200.

Comment: For the pin choice, I don't know why they made their choice, but the FtoF converter is more common (thus likey cheaper) than the MtoM one, and a gender switcher would be more problematic connected directly to the projector than between two cables.

Comment: Cheaper clones [are available](http://www.meritline.com/dvi-d-digital-to-vga-hv-format-converter-box---p-77486.aspx) but they're not as nice.

Comment: I guess it is made so to make analog cable as short as possible to keep noise low. You can connect it directly to VGA monitor/projector and use DVI cable between computer and the converter.

Comment: The picture is DVI-I and not DVI-D!!! DVI-D converters don't work, DVI-I converters do work!

Comment: The device *claims* to work with dvi-d. The physical layout of the female dvi connector needs to be dvi-i, otherwise it can't work with dvi-i outputs, and you need one converter for dvi-i and one for dvi-d.

Answer (score 1):

[Startech](http://www.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/High-Resolution-Video-DVI-to-VGA-Converter~DVI2VGACON) produces one as well and price is lower at most retail outlets.  web price is high